# ruby error: ' is not installed9.3-p194

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant, cloud-foundry

It happened when I was installing Cloud Foundry v2 on Virtual Box

git clone of cf-vagrant-installer was done on windows, then vagrant set up CloudFoundry on ubuntu virtual box and shared there this windows folder. 
Vagrant can't start Cloud Foundry due to error in subj.

Solution: In my case git converted text from unix style to windows style (LF -> CR+LF). This setting is selected when git is installed. I changed it to keep unix style and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the setting for Git to use Unix-style line-feeds.